# Is there any notification API for each likes/comment on Facebook post?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I am using Graph API to publish a post using Android facebook SDK. Now i want to get notifications whenever a users like/comments on that post. So I am wondering if there is any Notification API or some other api that facebook provides for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Reatime Updates API:

• https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3